# Specman: how to access a variable in a sequence?

Tags: sequence, specman, e

I have a variable in my Specman sequence that i am using as a flag. I would like to check that flag after the sequence is called. Is there a way to access that varible in the MAIN function after the sequence has updated its value?

Thanks

Comment: can you please further elaborate? is the variable that you want to access a local variable inside the body() TCM or a struct member of that sequence? is the sequence under the same sequence tree as the MAIN sequence that you mentioned here?

Comment: A sequence is just a struct variable (usually a field in the parent sequence). So if you can access this variable you can also access its fields, i.e. your flag.